# Why cant R vectors containing strings be replaced with numbers?

Tags: r, replace

I have a vector within an R dataframe wich literally contains an abbreviation for the months in a year in the form (JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC) and I want to replace them for their traditional equivalent [1:12]

came up with the following ideas, all of which give a vector filled with not available (NA) values.

```
replace(df$month, df$month == 'JAN', '01')

df$month <- if(df$month == "JAN") '01'

df$month <- match(df$month,month.abb)
```

the first two only make NA values were JAN was, the third one makes all months NA values

Any ideas why this isn't working, and how to get it to work?

Comment: You could just convert to a factor: df$month <- factor(df$month, levels = ("JAN", "FEB", "MAR", ...), labels = (1, 2, 3, ...))

Comment: I think what you have should work if `df$month` is a string and not a factor already.

Comment: If `x` is your input vector then try `match(x, toupper(month.abb))`

Comment: @PeterDee your solution works and I get the sense of it

Comment: @jraab i think so too.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck It did work, also its more compact than the other alternatives but what is this toupper() function?

Comment: At the R console try: `?toupper`

Comment: What's wrong with `df$month[df$month == "JAN"] <- "01"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be inclined to do this with `merge`.

```
MonthRef <- data.frame(month_number = 1:12,
                       month_abb = toupper(month.abb))
#* Make a data frame of random months
Months <- data.frame(month = sample(MonthRef$month_abb, 20, replace=TRUE))

merge(Months, MonthRef, by.x="month", by.y="month_abb")
```

It's a bit more typing, but it has the advantage that it will be very clear to me what I did when I come back to it in six months.